# How to get dozen of images without write a specific request to each image?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a html page, which contains table of images, and in order to load each image I'm using JS:

```
<img id="imageId">
$("#imageId").attr("src", srcLink);  // where srcLink = '/images/20180918_124058.jpg'
```

so for each image, I need to have a specific handle, like:

```
app.get('/images/20180918_124058.jpg', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile("/images/20180918_124058.jpg", {root: __dirname });
})
```

Is there option on the server (Node.JS) to handle all the dozen requests in one request (and parse the src link and send the right image back) ?

Comment: you can use promises for this. Just fetch all images you want and response the src´s inside an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there option on the server (Node.JS) to handle all the dozen requests in one request (and parse the src link and send the right image back) ?

Yes, there is.  You can create one route for all the images:

```
app.get('/images/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join("/images", req.params.id), {root: __dirname }, function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
    });
});
```

---

Or, you could use `express.static()` and have it serve the images for you from your `/images` directory:

```
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images"), {fallthrough: false}));
```

Note: both of these options will serve any matching URL/filename found in the `/images` directory so you need to make sure that there are ONLY files in that directory that you intend to be publicly available.